# Ubuntu 14.04 download page

Tags: system-installation

I found a link to download ubuntu for 
Ubuntu on HP ProLiant DL380 G7
on this link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201403-14898/
but, when trying to download this software, I get this error:

Not Found

The requested URL /releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso was not found on this server.

Does someonw know why?

Comment: Remove the `old-` at the beginning of the URL, then it works. But why don't you download from the official download page?

Comment: I posted a question about it: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/257917 . It should get fixed soon.

Answer (score 4):

Cause they messed up the URL. It should be http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/

What you are looking for is:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso

Answer (score -1):

Because 14.04 is end of life now. (extended support) the link to download is here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Comment: When the question was asked on `Nov 19 '14 at 17:37` 14.04 was perfectly supported. Also the link for download is wrong,

Comment: Agree - when the question was asked, 14.04 was perfectly supported.  I don't know why the link back then did not work.  My link above shows the current download location - and then you pick one .. like this. http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.6-server-amd64.iso 
What I haven't confirmed is how you pickup the last fixes .. this looks ok, but untested: https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/07/31/apt-repository-for-old-ubuntu-releases/